# How many Jedi (Knights) lived in the galaxy before The Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, statistics

How many Jedi (Knights) lived in the galaxy before The Clone Wars?

More to the point, what was the order of magnitude?

Can the total number of Jedi be approximated by the ones we see in the movies?

I would imagine that the Jedi did not all live in the vicinity of Coruscant. However, it is indicated in Episode III that most Jedi died due to Order 66.

Comment: As a note - I was only able to answer this question partially, so if anyone has better info, please jump in!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per "[Episode I: The Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_I:_The_Visual_Dictionary)" book, there were 10,000 Jedi at the time of The Phantom Menace on Corscant.

> Q. Approximately how many Jedi are on Coruscant at the time of Episode I?
>
> A. 10,000

I saw references to 1000 Jedi by the time of RotS, but don't know the source.

Comment: Not all jedi were on Coruscant. Most, but not all. There were other jedi training satellite facilities, and more out on assignments.

Comment: @Kevin - I wasn't able to find out anything about off-Coruscant ones.

Answer (score 17):

**10,000** Jedi (Knights) around the time of Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace according to the sources I detail below.

First, according to the [Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace novelization](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I%3a_The_Phantom_Menace_%28novel%29) by Terry Brooks and published on April 21, 1999:

> In the time of Qui-Gon Jinn, **ten thousand** Jedi Knights in service to
>   the Republic carried on the struggle each day of their lives in a
>   hundred thousand different worlds spread across a galaxy so vast it
>   could barely be comprehended.

Source: an Amazon.com Look Inside search for "ten thousand" on [its page for the novelization](http://amzn.com/0345434110).

Second, according to the young adult book [Episode I Adventures 1: Search for the Lost Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_I_Adventures_1%3a_Search_for_the_Lost_Jedi) published September 1, 1999:

> ... twelve member Jedi Council contemplated the Force and decided the action of **over ten thousand** Jedi Knights throughout the galaxy.

Source: a [Google book search](http://books.google.com/books?ei=eP8yT9SfHK6F0QG6lbTtBw&id=C96R_mHe6YkC&dq=ten%20thousand%20jedi&q=ten%20thousand%20jedi#search_anchor) for "ten thousand Jedi".

Third, according to a description on the LucasArts website for the video game [Star Wars Episode I: Jedi Power Battles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I%3a_Jedi_Power_Battles) released March 31, 2000 in North America:

> STORY
>
> Out of **10,000** Jedi in the Galactic Republic, you are the one.
>   Chosen by your peers, you now stand in the Jedi Council Chamber high
>   above the bustling metropolis of Coruscant. Encircled by great Jedi
>   who sit in the stately chamber, a mission of great importance to the
>   Republic is about to be bestowed upon you.

Source: [Archive.org Wayback capture of the LucasArts website dated June 15, 2000](http://web.archive.org/web/20000615081836/http://www.lucasarts.com/products/jedipowerbattles/overview.htm).

Aside: If we had access to GFFA census data like we do for [many English speaking countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jedi_census_phenomenon), this question would be a lot easier to answer. ;)

Comment: I guess having the Jedi religion doesn't necessarily mean being a Jedi, but just trusting in them.