# What were the immediate death tolls of Order 66?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, order-66

As accurately as sources can provide, what were the Jedi death tolls in the immediate aftermath of Order 66:

- On Coruscant, and how many by Anakin's hand?
- Outside Coruscant, across the galaxy, to the opening shots of Order 66?
- In the immediate days after, when the "Grand Army of the Empire" was still actively hunting down those who managed to escape?

In the context of this question, the immediate term ends when the inhibitor chips release their control of the clones i.e. when the actually-loyal-to-the-Republic-and-the-Jedi clone troopers regained free will.

**Edit**: I'm looking for a breakdown, not a grand total.

Comment: Even the younglings?

Comment: @MarkRogers "Every single Jedi, including your friend, Obi-Wan Kenobi, is now an enemy of the Republic...Do what must be done, Lord Vader. Do not hesitate. Show no mercy."

Comment: Related: [How many Jedi were there at the time of the purge?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/40252/21267)

Comment: The questions are slightly different, but [Thaddeus' answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/40255/5184) covers this.