# What kind of casualties did the Jedi Order face in the Clone Wars before Order 66?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-clone-wars

Throughout many of the works concerned with the Clone Wars, there is constant refrain of heavy casualties suffered by the Jedi during the War, with the Order stretched thin in numbers, and even young padawans being deployed to War.

The questions about [number of Jedi before Clone Wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/how-many-jedi-knights-lived-in-the-galaxy-before-the-clone-wars) and [number of Jedi at time of Order 66](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40252/how-many-jedi-at-the-time-of-the-purge) put both figures to be around 10,000. The difference seems to be that the previous number is the number of Jedi Knights and the latter of Jedi (presumably including Initiates and Padawans, and possibly also the Service Corps?).

As such, is there any other G-canon (*The Clone Wars* cartoon, perhaps?) or lower-canon source which gives

1) either any numbers on the the casualties suffered by the Jedi *before* Order 66 eliminated 99% of them?

2) or, indirectly, any numbers on the Initiate + Padawan (+ Service Corps?) population of the Jedi, which we could then take to be about equivalent to the presumed CW casualties pre-Order 66.

ETA: Possibly an answer to the question of how many young Initiates became Apprenticed, and how many 'flunked out' of the program into the Service Corps would also be helpful.

Comment: Don't forget there were substantial youngling casualities as well.

Comment: @overmann You mean, youngling casualties pre-Order 66? Can you elaborate more? I don't think I'm familiar with that part of things.

Comment: We know that there where extremely substantial losses in the battle of Geonosis.

Comment: Here's a start: http://ahurawerewolftheking.deviantart.com/art/Clone-Wars-Jedi-Casualty-List-142270034

Comment: @BitNinja Acc. to wiki, only 30-ish of the 212 Jedi in the Geonosis Strike Team survived. And while 200 out of 10,000 is not a negligible number either, it seems to me that the heavy casualties might be in reference to both: total number of jedi killed in 1 battle and % fatality of large Jedi team deployed; rather than heavy casualties in relation to total number dead during the wars.

Comment: @Shisa It's not really about the numbers there, more about _who_ was there, there were many high ranking members (council members even) who died in the arena.

Comment: @BennyMcBenBen so many names I can't pronounce...

Answer (score 3):

If you add up the casualties from [Geonosis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Geonosis_strike_team#Result) (est. 182) and all the other known Jedi [casualities](http://ahurawerewolftheking.deviantart.com/art/Clone-Wars-Jedi-Casualty-List-142270034) before Order 66 you get **303** known Jedi deaths.

Since we know Jedi take their Padawans on missions and into battle that would include Padawan deaths as well.