# What's the ratio of Force users to normal humans?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force

At the time of *Attack of the Clones*, there are about 10,000 Jedi in the galaxy. We also know of a few living Sith/Dark Side users and Force-sensitives. Is this number representative of the Force users in the galaxy? What is the exact ratio, if it exists?

Comment: Given that the population of the Sky River Galaxy is around [400 Quadrillion](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76427/20774) and the number of Jedi is [around 10000](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10315/20774)(ish), that gives us a ratio of 1:0. Essentially Force users represent around  0.000000000000001% of the general population.

Comment: So you want the ratio of force users of all species to non-force-using humans?

Comment: Whatever works for you as the answerer (I know that's not a word).

Comment: Somebody should inform the Oxford English Dictionary that "answerer" is not a word. They have a good-sized entry for it, with five senses and 40 or 50 quotations.

Comment: @user14111 - If that upsets you, might I suggest that you never, ever look at the updated definition for the word "*Ironic*"

Answer (score 4):

Given the massive size of the Old Republic and Galactic Empire and that members of seemingly every species can have the ability to use the Force but at the same time people don't believe it's a real thing, the number of people who actually are trained in its use must be negligible. The number of people who have the ability but don't know how to use it, like Luke and Leia, could be much higher, but the total number of Jedi, Sith, and others who can use Force Powers is apparently tiny compared to the galactic population.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which asked for the "***exact*** ratio". "Tiny" is not an exact ratio.

Comment: Since no actual number of the galactic population or the number of force users is ever stated anywhere, calculating the exact ratio is impossible. Eyeballing is as close as you can ever get when it comes to numbers in the Star Wars setting. (Or pretty much any fictional setting.)

Comment: I agree. Nevertheless, the OP explicitly demanded "the exact ratio." As to why he made such an impossible request, I have no idea, you'd have to ask him.