# How many Jedi were present at the Temple on Coruscant during the purge?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

As detailed in a [related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/40252/90310), it was estimated that there were around 10,000 Jedi at the time that they were wiped off the face of the galaxy by Clone Troopers. But how many Jedi were present at the Temple on Coruscant when the 501st and Darth Vader burst in?

Comment: [10,000, not 20,000](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10699/20774) (and that relates to the number in the galaxy *before* the Clone Wars started).

Comment: In all the novelizations and games it is only mentioned that nearly the entire order died with Operation Knightfall.  Doubt you will be getting any exact numbers because  of how weird the scale of everything is in the star wars Galaxy (Germany had more troops during WW2 then the Republic had clones to cover the entire galaxy for example). Because up until now those 10K jedi are the only actual number we got.

Comment: Boolean says that in WWII Germany had more trrops than the Republic had clones tokeeporder in an entire galaxy.  During WWII the USSR and the USA each had more troops than Germany.  So primitive Earth in WWII had more than three times as many troops mobilized as an advanced galactic government had in a galactic civil War.